# jQuery .toggleClass on specific container to add additional class

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have some html containers which are repeated on a page. Each container will contain large portions of text. As the text will span a considerable number of lines each container has a max-height so the containers arn't too big to scroll past with the overflow of the containers hidden so you have to scroll in them.

Using jquery, I want to have a button below each container which will expand only the specific container it is meant to work for.

How I want to do this is by using jquery to toggle a css class only on the specific container the button is meant for. I've inlcuded a snippet to show the concept and what I've managed to get working but currently my code adds the css class to every container not just the specific one.

Also I don't think I've written the jquery code properly either. It works in FireFox but not in the stackoverflow snippet, so help with understanding what I've written wrong there would also be much appreciated.

I've tried to figure it out and have tried to use similar answers to similar questions found on stackoverflow, but as I am still learning jquery I've gotten myself completely stuck with this.

```js
$("container-expand").click(function(){
  $(".container-box").toggleClass("container-box-expand");
});
```

```css
.container-box {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.container-box-expand {
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
<br/><br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
</div>
<button id="container-expand">Expand</button>

<br/><br/>

<div class="container-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
<br/><br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
</div>
<button id="container-expand">Expand</button>

<br/><br/>

<div class="container-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
<br/><br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A erat nam at lectus urna. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Duis ut diam quam nulla. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.
<br/><br/>
Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar.
<br/><br/>
Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis.
</div>
<button id="container-expand">Expand</button>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid. DOMHTML Elements have to have unique IDs (if you include them). if you'd like to use jQuery then target a CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else has said, your id's should be unique. Alternatively, make them classes.

If you make `container-expand` to be classes then you will need to alter your code like so...

```
$(".container-expand").click(function(){
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("container-box-expand");
});
```

The `this` keyword refers to the button you are clicking (otherwise using just the class name would mean both buttons) . The `.prev()` bit will return the sibling element that comes before that button, so 'container-box' and in turn the correct class will get added to the correct container div.